# Count to zero then Count up

Tags: python

Since im fairly new to python and programming i have a question of a very basic nature. I want to make a iteration function and a recursive function that does this:

```
bounce(4)

4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

I know it's propably very simple but any help would be appreciated.

My current code looks like this:

```
def bounce1(n):
    if n==0:
        print "0",
    else:
        print n,
        bounce1(n-1)

def bounce2(n):
    if n>=1:
        bounce2(n-1)
        print n

def bounce(n):
    bounce1(n)
    bounce2(n)
```

Comment: Recursion? Are you sure about this?

Comment: The `range` function will probably be useful to you. Did you know? You can give negative numbers to `range`'s third parameter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not for building programs for you, but for helping you with specific programming questions. Please post what code you have tried, and if you've tried nothing, attempt the problem yourself first.

Comment: @Kevin There's not need for the 3rd parameter of `range`: `f=lambda x:map(abs,range(-x,x+1)) [NEW LINE]
for x in f(4):print x,`

Comment: @Raindeerstream Your code works already. The indentation was just incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterative implementation:

```
>>> def bounce(num):
...     limit, delta = num + 1, -1
...     while(num != limit):
...         print num
...         num += delta
...         if num == 0:
...             delta = 1
```

Recursive implementation:

```
>>> def bounce(num):
...     print num
...     if num: 
...         bounce(num - 1)
...         print num
...         
...
```

Output in both the cases:

```
>>> bounce(4)
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: @Raindeerstream if that helped don't forget to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :) Also, I have added your code to your post, you can delete your answer now.

Comment: @mu無 Actually I added it to his post, and you edited my edit to add the tabs the OP had messed up.

Comment: @mbomb007 Didn't realize, most probably your edit would still be in the review queue, so mine would have overwritten it directly because of extra rep privileges ..

Answer (score 1):

If you *can* use `range`, I would do it like this in Python 2.7:

```
f = lambda x : map(abs, range(-x,x+1))
for x in f(4):
    print x,
```

Comment: Since this is homework for you, I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.

Comment: nice! +1 for map and abs

Comment: @mu無 Thanks, I didn't even know about `map` until recently. It's pretty handy.