# Python, Make an iterative function into a recursive function

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, recursion

I've created an iterative function which outputs 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4.

```
def bounce2(n):
    s = n
    for i in range(n):
        print(n)
        n = n-1

    if n <= 0:
        for i in range(s+1):
            print(-n)
            n = n-1
    return
bounce2(4)
```

If I want a recursive function that does the exact same thing, how should I think?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: keep in mind that semicolons in Python are optional for lines with a single statement, and the general recommendation is to leave them out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count to zero then Count up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417462/count-to-zero-then-count-up)

Comment: You shouldn't want a recursive function to replace an iterative one; Python doesn't handle recursion efficiently.

Comment: @chepner Unless it's an exercise to learn about recursion.

Comment: Since recursion is really only useful in Python for traversing recursive data structures, I doubt the utility of these types of conversions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
def bounce(n):
    if n >= 0:
        print(n)
        bounce(n - 1)

        if n:
            print(n)

bounce(4)
```

the output will be:
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 2):

Expected output:

```
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

Let me put it into a diagram:

```
4
  3
    2
      1
        0
      1
    2
  3
4
```

Let's put that into code:

```
def bounce(n):
    print(n)
    if n:
        bounce(n - 1)
        print(n)
```

Or I can see it as a tree traversal - down and up (well, the tree is pretty linear in this case):

```
↓
  4
↓ | ↑
  3
↓ | ↑
  2
↓ | ↑
  1
↓ | ↑
  0
```

There are multiple ways how to do a [tree traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree-traversal), I would pick DFS here - [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

DFS pseudocode:

```
procedure DFS(G,v):
    label v as discovered
    for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
        if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
            recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

Actually it's designed for graphs, not just trees; for trees we don't have to do the "label as discovered" part.

Translate this DFS to Python:

```
def dfs(node):
    for child_node in node:
        dfs(child_node)
```

In the `4 3 2 1 0` case we don't need the `for` becase there is exactly one or zero child nodes - `n - 1` as long as `n > 0`:

```
def our_dfs(n):
    if n > 0:
        child_node = n - 1
        our_dfs(child_node)
```

But that does just the traversal and nothing really useful yet. Let's inject our "business logic":

```
def bounce(n):
    # stuff that happens before we go down
    print(n)
    # descend
    if n > 0:
        child_node = n - 1
        bounce(child_node)
    # stuff that happens after we are back from processing the subtree
    if n > 0:
        print(n)
```

Because we believe in good craftsmanship and we want to produce clean code (OK I am starting to be joking now) we want functions that do only one thing - one function for DFS, one function that represents our tree, separate function(s) for our business logic:

```
def dfs(node, child_factory, before_stuff, after_stuff):
    before_stuff(node)
    for child_node in get_child_nodes(node):
        dfs(child_node, child_factory, before_stuff, after_stuff)
    after_stuff(node)

def get_child_nodes(n):
    if n:
        yield n - 1

def print_before(node):
    print(node)

def print_after(node):
    if node:
        print(node)

def bounce(n):
    dfs(n, get_child_nodes, print_before, print_after)

bounce(4)
```

Maybe we could make the `dfs` function a bit simpler by using nested function:

```
def dfs(node, child_factory, before_stuff, after_stuff):
    def f(node):
        before_stuff(node)
        for child_node in get_child_nodes(node):
            f(child_node)
        after_stuff(node)
    f(node)
```

Hey, lookign at it, I have one more idea... We could modify this to a function that returns a function ([closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857/can-you-explain-closures-as-they-relate-to-python)) that can do DFS:

```
def make_dfs(child_factory, before_stuff, after_stuff):
    def dfs(node):
        before_stuff(node)
        for child_node in get_child_nodes(node):
            dfs(child_node)
        after_stuff(node)
    return dfs
```

So the bounce program now becomes:

```
def get_child_nodes(n):
    if n:
        yield n - 1

def print_before(node):
    print(node)

def print_after(node):
    if node:
        print(node)

def make_dfs(child_factory, before_stuff, after_stuff):
    def dfs(node):
        before_stuff(node)
        for child_node in get_child_nodes(node):
            dfs(child_node)
        after_stuff(node)
    return dfs

bounce = make_dfs(get_child_nodes, print_before, print_after)

bounce(4)
```

So, what's so cool about this solution? (note: still joking, partially) You know, Python has a [recursion limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it). There is a finite number of how many function calls can be nested and this number is pretty low. That's a big downside (sometimes even security concern) of processing unknown inputs using recursive functions. So what now? Well, just replace the implementation of `make_dfs` with something stack-based (see that DFS Wikipedia page) instead of recursion. Done. You don't have to touch anything else.

Answer (score 1):

@mehrdad-pedramfar posted an excellent answer. Also you can try this more elaborate one:

```
def my_recursion(current_value, first_portion):
    if current_value == 5:
        return
    print(current_value)
    if current_value == 0 or not first_portion:
        my_recursion(current_value + 1, False)

    elif first_portion:
        my_recursion(current_value - 1, True)


my_recursion(4, True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically the same as the first. The output is differ - you'll get double 0.
Just to show you can print before and after recursive call.

```
def bounce(n):

    if n >= 0:
        print(n)
        bounce(n - 1)
        print(n)
```

3
2
1
0
0
1
2
3